ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED при попытке запука приложения .NET 6 локально
Перечитал много подобных ресурсов, где разные варианты, перепробовал очень многое, в моем случае вообще ничего не помогло.
Проблема: Есть .NET 6 приложение, которое относительно недавно нормально работало локально. Теперь при запуске ошибка в браузере ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.Я пробовал очень многое (работаю в Rider, в том числе пробовал в папке .idea удалять applicationhost.config - не помогло).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина, если раньше работал localhost а сейчас уже нет. Если создаю новый проект, то все работает отлично. Вот такой у меня launchSettings.json.
    {
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:48798",
      "sslPort": 44361
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "LeokaEstetica.Platform.Backend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9992",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

